# Trimmed too deep on door side, can I save this edge?

Tags: repair, wood, doors, adhesive, cutting

On the long side of my door, I was trimming using a saw (I know, I now own a planer) and my angle was too deep.  I realized it and stopped, so now I have a cut with the outside piece still attached at one end.

I was wondering if just wood glue or gorilla glue would be enough to rejoin the sides?  After it sets, I could plane it to try to get it a bit more even.

[image: photo of cut]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have nothing to lose by trying. Cut the remaining web so the sliver is completely off, then re-glue. Clamp well. Fill the cracks after everything dries.

If you haven't already, consider painting the door, as that will hide the filler.